# Need to migrate my all existing data to either on cloud spanner or cloud-datastore

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-spanner

I have my existing data in Cassandra on-premises on 8 servers and now I plan to move to either cloud spanner or cloud-datastore, so is there any way I can migrate my all existing data to any of them.

Also which one is good?

Answer (score 1):

For importing data into Cloud Spanner, please take a look at: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/import-non-spanner

Answer (score 0):

I undestand that Cassandra is a NoSQL database, therefore i will choose Cloud Datastore follow the next links:

https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/